# Парсинг страницы на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, link, parse

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно из [сайта](https://mtkspb.ru/public/educational/schedule/index.php) "вытащить" все ссылки из таблицы и сохранить их в PDF *(Расписание занятий на XX.XX.XXXX)*?

Comment: Предоставьте минимально воспроизводимый пример, код который вы написали, и что именно у вас не получается, что бы мы могли быстрее вам помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать вот так, с помощью библиотек re и requests. Очень минималистично, на стандартной библиотеке. Сначала мы получаем текст страницы, потом в нем ищем совпадения с нашим паттерном `pattern`

На странице ссылки хранятся как бы в  обрезанном формате, поэтому мы к ним добавляем адрес сервера в конце

```py
import re
import requests

pattern=re.compile(r'href="(?P<link>/[^\"]+.pdf)"') # регулярное выражение, которое находит ссылки

url="https://mtkspb.ru/public/educational/schedule/index.php"

text=requests.get(url).text # запрос к серверу,  и получаем текст страницы

matches=pattern.findall(text) # ищем все ссылки, тут они будут в относительном формате, без сервера
for l in matches:
    print("https://mtkspb.ru"+l) # вот тут добавляем к ним адрес сервера
```

Comment: `requests` это не стандартная библиотека